# db_query is not working in drupal 

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

hiii
  db_query gives empty result for some keywords .Here is my query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE first_name LIKE '%$first_name%'";
```

It works correctly if the $first_name is Deepak , but not works for deepak.

This is not case sensitivity issue. Becausse it works for other letters. the problem is with the letters staring with d, n,b etc(i think %d, $n,%b working here ).Is there any way to avoid this?
can u please suggest a solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE first_name LIKE '%%$first_name%'";
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like:

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE first_name LIKE '%%s%'", $first_name);
```